# How do I convert Opendrive xodr file to net.xml for SUMO

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sumo, traffic-simulation

Conversion has to be done with 'Netconvert' tool.
I am facing error and cmd prompt quitting on negative speed error.

How do I over come this issue? Is there a way I can ignore speed?

Output should be with Net.xml format file.
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi MedaBoy, help us helping you by pasting the code and the error message (not images, text please) into your question, so that we can examine it.

Comment: If you can share your input it would also help a lot

Comment: Thank you @Michael, I did use the --speed.minimum , I could able to generate the file.

Comment: If you think your xodr file is legitimate input and should somehow be handled by sumo's netconvert please open an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the options `--speed.offset` and `--speed.minimum` to modify / ensure edge speeds but you should probably check your input first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMO's built in file converter:

`netconvert --opendrive-files xodrfilename -o newfile.net.xml`